# How to write this SQL using Rails' read methods?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following setup:

question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers

    #validations, methods, etc
    ...

    #Returns the questions with the most answers
    def Question.top_questions(max = 10)
        sql = "SELECT question_id, COUNT('question_id') as aCount FROM answers GROUP BY question_id ORDER BY aCount DESC LIMIT #{max.to_i}" # Probably shouldn't use string interpolation here :D
        Question.connection.execute(sql)
    end
end
```

answer.rb

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
    ...
end
```

And if I call Question.top_questions(), then it returns this:

> [{"question_id"=>1, "aCount"=>25, 0=>1, 1=>25}, {"question_id"=>38, "aCount"=>3, 0=>38, 1=>3}, {"question_id"=>45, "aCount"=>3, 0=>45, 1=>3}, {"question_id"=>26, "aCount"=>2, 0=>26, 1=>2}, {"question_id"=>46, "aCount"=>2, 0=>46, 1=>2}, {"question_id"=>48, "aCount"=>2, 0=>48, 1=>2}, {"question_id"=>51, "aCount"=>2, 0=>51, 1=>2}, {"question_id"=>5, "aCount"=>1, 0=>5, 1=>1}, {"question_id"=>15, "aCount"=>1, 0=>15, 1=>1}, {"question_id"=>20, "aCount"=>1, 0=>20, 1=>1}]

I'm not sure how I would use the data returned in a view while still keeping the code clean.
So I'm wondering if I could write the `Question.top_questions()` method using rails' read methods(find(), where(), etc). Or how I could get it to return an array of Question objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns an array of hashes, you could use it in a view as you like.

But if you don't want to write native sql, you could rewrite it as below.

```
def self.top_questions(max = 10)
    Question.joins('LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.question_id')
            .select('questions.*, count(answers.id) as answers_count')
            .group('questions.id')
            .order('answers_count desc')
            .limit(max)        
end
```